# Django Simple History INSERTS rather than UPDATES when reverting a model

Tags: python, django, django-simple-history

I'm reverting a model instance as specified in the [docs](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/querying_history.html#reverting-the-model):

```py
# In a DRF ViewSet, although I don't think that should matter...
instance = self.get_object()

# Find the historical record I want
desired_record = instance.history.first().prev_record

# Get the instance from it (I removed code handling the edge case of no prior history, for question clarity)
desired_instance = desired_record.instance

# EDIT, I have also tried 
# desired_instance = instance.history.most_recent()
# which exhibits the same problem on save

# Include a changelog comment
desired_instance._change_reason = "Reverted to previous"

# Update the instance
desired_instance.save()
```

However, this produces the error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "projects_configuration_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(9ffc4e31-e714-4258-95dd-a196a70bf301) already exists.
```

The model (in app `projects`) looks like:

```py
class Configuration(models.Model)
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    name = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, max_length=60)
```

The same problem occurs when I use the `instance.history.as_of(<datetime>)` method.

**DSH seems to be attempting to insert a new record rather than update the existing one to a former state. What's going on here?**

Answer (score 1):

It turns out this is a [known issue](https://github.com/jazzband/django-simple-history/issues/617) related to the UUIDField (a django 3.0 [backward incompatibility](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/releases/3.0/#backwards-incompatible-changes-in-3-0)) with a workaround:

```py
# Find the historical record you want (use `most_recent`, `as_of`, or whatever method)
desired_record = instance.history.first().prev_record 
desired_instance = desired_record.instance

# Include a changelog comment
desired_instance._change_reason = "Reverted to previous"

# Tell django >3.0 that it's being updated, not added
desired_instance._state.adding = False

# And force save it
desired_instance.save(force_update=True)
```

Comment: Ugh yes. I remember now I didn't like that change when I read it in the changelog.